# CollectionViewCell is no displayed receiving data from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have to fill the cells with data from the firebase. But they are not displayed. Help and explain where I made a mistake.
How to fill cell data ?

```
class TrainingProgramViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    //var trainingPrograms = TrainingProgram.fetchTrainingProgram()
    var trainingPrograms = [TrainingProgram]()
    let cellScale: CGFloat = 0.7


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchPrograms()

    }

    func fetchPrograms() {
        Database.database().reference().child("programs").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                print(dict)
                let newTitle = dict["title"] as! String
                print("Новый тайтл:" + newTitle)
                let newDescription = dict["description"] as! String
                let trainingCell = TrainingProgram(description: newDescription, title: newTitle)
                self.trainingPrograms.append(trainingCell)
                print(self.trainingPrograms)
            }
        }
    }


}

extension TrainingProgramViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return trainingPrograms.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TrainingProgramCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as!  TrainingProgramCollectionViewCell
        let trainingProgram = trainingPrograms[indexPath.item]
        cell.trainingPrograms = trainingProgram

        return cell

    }
```

This is a model:

```
class TrainingProgram
{
    var description = ""
    var title = ""


    init(description: String, title: String) {
        self.description = description
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

This is my structure of Database :[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to reload your collectionView

```
func fetchPrograms() {
    Database.database().reference().child("programs").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            print(dict)
            let newTitle = dict["title"] as! String
            print("Новый тайтл:" + newTitle)
            let newDescription = dict["description"] as! String
            let trainingCell = TrainingProgram(description: newDescription, title: newTitle)
            self.trainingPrograms.append(trainingCell)
            print(self.trainingPrograms)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self. collectionView.reloadData()
          }
    }
}
```

Also set

```
 collectionView.delegate = self
 collectionView.dataSource = self
```

In your collectionView Method

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TrainingProgramCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as!  TrainingProgramCollectionViewCell
    cell.titleLabel.text = trainingPrograms[indexPath.item].title

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Did not help :(

Answer (score 0):

After you fetch the data and append it to your array which is shown in your tableView/collectionView you always have to `reloadData()` like `collectionView.reloadData()` or `tableView.reloadData()`